# How to change the selected option of a select box onload?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am working on a project, where i have to select a particular option of a select box, i know how to do this, but the problem is a function must be called whenever value of select box changes, when we do it manually it works, but when i do it with jquery onload, that function not works. Because it only work when a user manually change the option from select box. Please tell me how to do this.

example:

```
          <select>
               <option val="0" selected></option>
               <option val="1"></option>
               <option val="2"></option>
               <option val="3"></option>
               <option val="4"></option>
               <option val="5"></option>
          </select>
```

here is some of my efforts which i have tried:

```
$("select").val('5');
```

Comment: i remember that i had similar problems. Just call $("select").change() after you set the value

Comment: here is the running site, http://54.66.136.29/SplitsBrowser/splits-graph-template.html , i just need to select last option from the dropdown, and also need to call the function automatically which runs on manual changes, just select the last value from the dropdown you can see at the top of the page

Comment: Your site is loading it's content via AJAX so you cannot run anything on load - you need to update the selec *after* the AJAX calls have completed.

Comment: you can test it from console, trigger change event once value changed works. Rory is correct

Answer (score 7):

You wish to pre-select an option when the page first loads?

This bit of jQuery will find the `option` with the value of 5 and select it. By wrapping it in the `jQuery(document).ready` function it will run once the page has loaded.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('select').find('option[value=5]').attr('selected','selected');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="0" selected>0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: man of all the problems i can solve, it's this one.  i've tried all these solution and that damn list box wont select.

Answer (score 2):

Guess what, it is simple.

Your Select Component :

```
<select id="YourSelectComponentID">
            <option value="0">Apple</option>
            <option value="2">Banana</option>
            <option value="3">Cat</option>
            <option value="4">Dolphin</option>
</select>
```

Copy and paste this in your javaScript section.

```
$(function(){
   document.getElementById("YourSelectComponentID").value = 4;
});
```

Now your option 4 will be selected whenever the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

> using this you can change the value of select box when page loads

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('select').find('option[value=USD]').attr('selected','selected');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
   <option value="JPY">Japanese yen (JPY)</option>
<option value="AFN">Afghan afghani (AFN)</option>
<option value="ALL">Albanian lek (ALL)</option>
<option value="DZD">Algerian dinar (DZD)</option>
<option value="AOA">Angolan kwanza (AOA)</option>
<option value="ARS">Argentine peso (ARS)</option>
<option value="AMD">Armenian dram (AMD)</option>
<option value="AWG">Aruban florin (AWG)</option>
<option value="USD">United States dollar (USD)</option>
</select>
```